# Compare Two Ordered Lists in C#

Tags: c#, performance, list-comparison

The problem is that I have two lists of strings. One list is an approximation of the other list, and I need some way of measuring the accuracy of the approximation.

As a makeshift way of scoring the approximation, I have bucketed each list(the approximation and the answer) into 3 partitions (high, medium low) after sorting based on a numeric value that corresponds to the string. I then compare all of the elements in the approximation to see if the string exists in the same partition of the correct list.

I sum the number of correctly classified strings and divide it by the total number of strings.  I understand that this is a very crude way of measuring the accuracy of the estimate, and was hoping that better alternatives were available. This is a very small component of a larger piece of work, and was hoping to not have to reinvent the wheel.

EDIT:
I think I wasn't clear enough. I don't need the two lists to be exactly equal, I need some sort of measure that shows the lists are similar. For example, The High-Medium-Low (H-M-L) approach we have taken shows that the estimated list is sufficiently similar. The downside of this approach is that if the estimated list has an item at the bottom of the "High" bracket, and in the actual list, the item is at the top of the medium set, the score algorithm fails to deliver.

It could potentially be that in addition to the H-M-L approach, the bottom 20% of each partition is compared to the top 20% of the next partition or something along those lines.

Thanks all for your help!!

Comment: How about posting some relevant code instead of *describing* it? Together with input, output and *expected-output*.

Comment: Can you post your code ??

Comment: Sounds like a full outer join. Diffing lists is always a full outer join.

Comment: @AnthonyWood Are the lists always the same size?

Comment: Why is my code relevant? I am asking for a new algorithm. The lists are of strings, therefore the solutions is generic to any strings. Input comes from different csv files which are converted to an in-memory matrix. Output would be the most accurate score possible

Comment: @AymenDaoudi Why is my code relevant? I am asking for a new algorithm. The lists are of strings, therefore the solutions is generic to any strings. Input comes from different csv files which are converted to an in-memory matrix. Output would be the most accurate score possible and lists in practice may be varying in length, but should theoretically be the same length

Comment: What's the point in dividing into partition when you're still just checking number of matching elements?

Comment: The lists are ordered based on some value, I am checking to see if the items have been categorised correctly into HML

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. Well, I think you could use the following method to compare your lists:

```
 public double DetermineAccuracyPercentage(int numberOfEqualElements, int yourListsLength)
    {
        return ((double)numberOfEqualElements / (double)yourListsLength) * 100.0; 
    }
```

The number returned should determine how much equality exists between your two lists. 
If  numberOfEqualElements = yourLists.Length (Count) so they are absolutely equal.
The accuracy of the approximation = (numberOfEqualElements / yourLists.Length) 
1 = completely equal , 0 = absolutely different, and the values between 0 and 1 determine the level of equality. In my sample a percentage.

If you compare these 2 lists, you will retrieve a 75% of equality, the same that 3 of 4 equal elements (3/4).

```
        IList<string> list1 = new List<string>();
        IList<string> list2 = new List<string>();

        list1.Add("Dog");
        list1.Add("Cat");
        list1.Add("Fish");
        list1.Add("Bird");

        list2.Add("Dog");
        list2.Add("Cat");
        list2.Add("Fish");
        list2.Add("Frog");


          int resultOfComparing = list1.Intersect(list2).Count();
        double accuracyPercentage = DetermineAccuracyPercentage(resultOfComparing,   list1.Count);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Your `CompareTwoLists` method could simply be implemented as `list1.Intersect(list2).Count();`

Comment: Thanks for this, not the answer exactly, but some of the content is useful, for improving my existing implementation! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

So, we're taking a sequence of items and grouping it into partitions with three categories, high, medium, and low.  Let's first make an object to represent those three partitions:

```
public class Partitions<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> High { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Medium { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Low { get; set; }
}
```

Next to make an estimate we want to take two of these objects, one for the actual and one for the estimate.  For each priority level we want to see how many of the items are in both collections; this is an "Intersection"; we want to sum up the counts of the intersection of each set.

Then just divide that count by the total:

```
public static double EstimateAccuracy<T>(Partitions<T> actual
    , Partitions<T> estimate)
{
    int correctlyCategorized = 
        actual.High.Intersect(estimate.High).Count() +
        actual.Medium.Intersect(estimate.Medium).Count() +
        actual.Low.Intersect(estimate.Low).Count();

    double total = actual.High.Count()+
        actual.Medium.Count()+
        actual.Low.Count();

    return correctlyCategorized / total;
}
```

Of course, if we generalize this to not 3 priorities, but rather a sequence of sequences, in which each sequence corresponds to some bucket (i.e. there are N buckets, not just 3) the code actually gets easier:

```
public static double EstimateAccuracy<T>(
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> actual
    , IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> estimate)
{
    var query = actual.Zip(estimate, (a, b) => new
    {
        valid = a.Intersect(b).Count(),
        total = a.Count()
    }).ToList();
    return query.Sum(pair => pair.valid) /
        (double)query.Sum(pair => pair.total);
}
```

Comment: @AlbertoMontellano For an answer.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. But isn't the same logic to solve the problem the same that question is using? is he asking for another way?

Comment: @AlbertoMontellano I think you are the only person who correctly understood my question. I have implemented the partition enumerable extensions, but these are helpful for refining my implementation

Answer (score 0):

I would take both `List<String>`s and combine each element into a `IEnumerable<Boolean>`:

```
public IEnumerable<Boolean> Combine<Ta, Tb>(List<Ta> seqA, List<Tb> seqB)
{
  if (seqA.Count != seqB.Count)
    throw new ArgumentException("Lists must be the same size...");

  for (int i = 0; i < seqA.Count; i++)
    yield return seqA[i].Equals(seqB[i]));
}
```

And then use `Aggregate()` to verify which strings match and keep a running total:

```
var result = Combine(a, b).Aggregate(0, (acc, t)=> t ? acc + 1 : acc) / a.Count;
```

Comment: You are assuming that the lists are of equal length. I don't think that is given.

Comment: @usr From what the OP described... I don't know exactly how else it would work.

Comment: I don't know what the OP described exactly. My approach: wait for clarification (or close).

Comment: @usr I don't disagree.  But I think I was able to read between the lines enough to infer the intention.

Comment: @Andrew as per comment above the lists should be of equal length.